# Express middleware passing variable, error 'TypeError: Cannot destructure property' in middleware function but works via route definiton

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, middleware

I am using pug templates in express and have a layout which has my top navigation toolbar etc. Inside this layout (viewable on all routes) I want to include a count of some items in the toolbar (without having to include the request for each pages/route definition ideally). So I thought I should use middleware.

I am able to use the response `userProfile` anywhere on the page in the /user view eg but when I try to add the `const {_raw, _json, ...userProfile} = req.user;` to the middleware I get the error `TypeError: Cannot destructure property`_raw`of 'undefined' or 'null'.`

Is this to do with parsing? Please help me understand. I am trying to reduce overhead therefor per route definitions would be fine but would like to understand why this call won't work, it seems like it would be very useful to display info you want on all routes.

This works but only via views (can use const in the layout but would need to redefine for each route which seems laborious),

```
    router.get('/user', secured(), (req, res, next) => {
        const {_raw, _json, ...userProfile} = req.user; // this works on routes
        res.render('user', {
            viewTitle: 'Profile',
            userProfile: JSON.stringify(userProfile, null, 2),
        });
    });
```

But this attempt (to use it on all pages via middleware) doesn't,

```
    module.exports = function () {
        return function (req, res, next) {
            const { _raw, _json, ...userProfile } = req.user;
            res.locals = {
                userProfile: JSON.stringify(userProfile, null, 2), // gives error in middleware but works in routes
                // userProfile: req.user, // tried this too //                    
                user: req.user,
                token: '1234',
                isAuthenticated: req.isAuthenticated(),
            };
            next();
        };
    };
```

app.js

```
app.use(express.json());// sets content-type to json
app.use(userInViews());
app.use('/', authRouter);
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/', usersRouter);
app.use('/', postRoutes);
app.use('/calendar', calendarRouter);
app.use('/bookings', usersRouter);
app.use('/add', usersRouter);
app.use('/edit', usersRouter);
app.use('/list', usersRouter);
app.use('/delete', usersRouter);
app.use('/calendar', usersRouter);
app.use('/dashboard', usersRouter);
app.use('/search', usersRouter);
app.use('/user', usersRouter);
```

Why can I get other variables and use them in the middleware for all routes but when calling `const { _raw, _json, ...userProfile } = JSON.stringify(userProfile, null, 2),` in the middleware I get the above error. What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: Please show how do you use this middleware after you defined it

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I am using it on my main app.js `app.use(userInViews());` I will edit to include my use.

Comment: I am guessing you are using passport or something similar for authentication since you are trying to access `req.user`. What is probably happening is that the middleware that creates the req.user is called after your `userInViews` middleware thus leaving it undefined.

Comment: The middleware I'm referring to is the function returned from the `secured` factory call that you make in your route definition.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, that is correct I am using passport auth0, but I think am only using one middleware function as above? And `req.user` does work on the /user route - should I create another middleware function before `app.use(userInViews());`? I have tried to use another query to mongoose but the result is the same that I can only use the result on the defined route and not globally.

Comment: Aha, I thought that because my index page is not using `secured` that it would render there at least.

Comment: I still am not able to access the object. I only get Object Object returned.

Comment: Although may not be relevant to your problem `router.get('/user', secured(), (req, res, next) => {` should rather be `router.get('/user', secured, (req, res, next) => {`

Comment: Thank you for the reply but my `secured` is a module exports function.