# Node js + passport+express

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I am trying to get the information of logged in user by writing a middleware and setting res.locals.currentUser=req.user but req.user is undefined even after user is logged In.Here is my passport configuration
//passport configuration

```
app.use(require("express-session")({
    secret:"ki keh sakde aa",
    resave:false,
    saveUninitialized:false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.use(new localStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can access the user object from Passport in the global scope, I believe you need to pass it to the routes you want to use.

I may be wrong but I had the same problem trying to get the user details to show in a toolbar across all pages. Still haven't found a proper work around.

Link to my same problem: [Express middleware passing variable, error 'TypeError: Cannot destructure property' in middleware function but works via route definiton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59407665/express-middleware-passing-variable-error-typeerror-cannot-destructure-proper?noredirect=1#comment105008420_59407665)

Comment: In order to avoid the req.user to routes in which i am going to use it.I have written a middleware which is   app.use(function(req,res,next){
    res.locals.currentUser=req.user;
    next();
});

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this maybe

```
const userProfile = req.user;
    res.locals = {
        userProfile: JSON.stringify(userProfile, null, 2),
        name: userProfile.displayName,
        loggedInEmail: userProfile.emails[0].value,
        isAuthenticated: req.isAuthenticated(),
    };
```